# Photoshop file gone to 0 bytes, all work lost

Tags: windows-8, adobe-photoshop, dropbox

There is this Photoshop file (webdesign) I had been working on yesterday for approx. the whole day, and it was hosted on Dropbox. When I was working on the psd file, dropbox was on the whole time and it saved all my work. As the biggest idiot I am, when I decided to finish, I pressed ctrl + S to save and instantly switched off the computer from the main power supply (don't ask me why), giving enough time to save the file on my computer but not sync on DropBox.

As I wake up today and switch on my computer (Windows 8 Pro x86) I instantly get boot time errors (W8 stupidity) and when I open up photoshop the computer crashes instantly, after taking some tricks out of the bag I got up and running again. When I opened up the photoshop file from yesterday, it had some errors but after all came up where I left off. When it instantly crashes. So I boot the computer up again, as I notice all progress has been lost and the photoshop file has shrunken from 6.65mb down to 0 bytes. I was shocked and was hoping dropbox had somehow recovered it, when I check dropbox it seems it has the oldest version of the file (not recent).

Right now, I am still panicking as I have lost a bunch of work. And would be interested on how to recover this :) Maybe through restoring my pc to a different time-frame would help, but I need your advice first :) Thanks alot, I will never use windows 8 again and most importantly never ever turn my pc from the main power switch (I am an idiot).

Thanks for your time, it is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can blame Windows 8 for this!

Answer (score 1):

If it's enabled, you can try to restore an earlier version via Windows' Previous Versions.

- Open Explorer.
- Navigate to `\\localhost\c$` (replace `c` with the drive letter of the drive your DropBox folder is located on).
- Click your way to where you DropBox folder is.
- Right-click the DropBox folder.
- Select "Restore previous versions"
- Double-click the version of that folder you want to open. (Hopefully there will one from a date/time that's usable to you).
- Find the file you want, and copy it some place (like say, your desktop).

More info on how to use Previous Versions in Windows 8 is [here](http://winhowto.blogspot.ca/2012/09/windows-8-how-to-recover-previous.html).

Comment: Great tip, but my pc has automatically decided not to ever make previous versions of any file. But that was a great tip thanks :)

Comment: Anyway, there is .tmp file in the directory that may be useful which as created when saving the photoshop file when it was disturbed. Don't know how you would take it from here, thanks :)